# QGraphicsitem sceneEvent handler

Tags: c++, qt

What I am trying to implement is the following:

I have a QGraphicsitem I could use **mouse or finger** to press and drag on it, so its color will change gradually depend on the drag.

Also I would like to resize it using touch event.

I have already done all the mouse related event handler like mousePressEvent, mouseMoveEvent and mouseReleaseEvent. And it seems the touch event is translated into a mouse event by default under Windows.

Now I add the following code to re-implement the graphicItem's sceneEvent function:

```
bool MapGraphicItem::sceneEvent(QEvent * event)
    {
        switch (event->type()) {
        case QEvent::TouchBegin:
        case QEvent::TouchUpdate:
        case QEvent::TouchEnd:
            QTouchEvent *touchEvent = static_cast<QTouchEvent *>(event);
            QList<QTouchEvent::TouchPoint> touchPoints = touchEvent->touchPoints();
            if (touchPoints.count() == 2) {
                //do the zoom
                }
            return true;
        }

        return QGraphicsItem::sceneEvent(event);
    }
```

The zoom also works, the problem is during pinch zoom, the mouse Events are also triggered so the color is changed which I don't want.

How to deal with this?

Comment: while you are doing the zoom, i guess the `QGRaphicsItem` does still get the `mouseMove` event. you might only need to add a boolean variable that blocks the move while you zoom

Answer (score 0):

Qt does automatically generate "synthesized" mouse events to allow an application only designed for a mouse to work on a touchscreen.

To discriminate between events coming from a physical mouse and synthesized ones, you can do as follows:

1. move all your graphic item's event handling code from mousePressEvent, mouseMoveEvent and mouseReleaseEvent to the sceneEvent method. You should add cases to your switch statement for case QEvent::GraphicsSceneMousePress, QEvent::GraphicsSceneMouseMove and QEvent::GraphicsSceneMouseRelease.
2. in the sceneEvent cases stated above, check that the event that you are receiving is coming from a physical mouse and not synthesized. Do this by casting the event pointer to QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent* and only handling events for which the source() method returns Qt::MouseEventNotSynthesized

Example:

```
bool MapGraphicItem::sceneEvent(QEvent * event)
{
    switch (event->type()) {
    case QEvent::GraphicsSceneMousePress:
        if (event && ((QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent*)event)->source() == Qt::MouseEventNotSynthesized)
            handleMousePress();
        return true;
    case QEvent::GraphicsSceneMouseMove:
        if (event && ((QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent*)event)->source() == Qt::MouseEventNotSynthesized)
            handleMouseMove();
        return true;
    case QEvent::GraphicsSceneMouseRelease:
        if (event && ((QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent*)event)->source() == Qt::MouseEventNotSynthesized)
            handleMouseRelease();
        return true;
    // i left the rest of your while block unchanged
    case QEvent::TouchBegin:
    case QEvent::TouchUpdate:
    case QEvent::TouchEnd:
        QTouchEvent *touchEvent = static_cast<QTouchEvent *>(event);
        QList<QTouchEvent::TouchPoint> touchPoints = touchEvent->touchPoints();
        if (touchPoints.count() == 2) {
            //do the zoom
            }
        return true;
    }

    return QGraphicsItem::sceneEvent(event);
}
```